# Access is denied while using Zend Tool in Zend Studio

Tags: zend-studio, zend-tool

Why do I get this error:

```
executing zf show actions
    Access is denied
```

When using Zend Tool in Zend Studio.

I do everything like in this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TqJs270tKg4

EDIT:

I noticed that when I create a project in ZS with ZT the projects location is in the ZS workspace (C:\Users\user\Zend\workspaces\DefaultWorkspace7\testProject). ZT works fine, but I can't test the application on the server (I'm using Zend Server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run ZendStudio as Administrator - right click on ZendStudio icon and choose Run as Administrator